# Setting SVN Environment var from batch file

Tags: batch-file

How to set environmental var from batch file for SVN I tried setting it like ...

Variable name: SVN_SSH

Variable value: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe or C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoisePlink.exe

However this is or no use. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: How did you try to set the variable ? through the UI ? If so you have to keep in mind that any cmd.exe started prior to the changes must be restarted so that it takes effect.

Comment: I tried using UI ...I restarted CMD.exe and also restarted system but no use cmd prompt still says 'SVN' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I want to also set it in  batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install SVN ? I am not clear with what you want to do. Can you tell me what is your final goal ? It'll be easier to help.

Tortoise doesn't provide the "svn.exe" program. You need to install the command line SVN client. You can find a list of those clients [here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows). Alternatively you can try using Tortoise EXEs but, I am not sure whether their command line is compatible with SVN.

Then you need to set your PATH environment variable where you installed your command line client.

Comment: @JN: I want to use SVN commands like SVN info,SVN cleanup as in linux in similar way I want to use in batch file. I do have TortoiseSVN installed in my system(windows 7).                                                 I think to use SVN commands in batch file i need to set environmental var. And as this batch file will be used by many if possible I also want to set environmental var for SVN through batch file only

Comment: @Enosh: TortoiseSVN is not the same as the command-line SVN client. Go install it, it will set the PATH automatically for you. It appears that the question you asked has no connection whatsoever to your problem currently.

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit
                 /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt*c:\svn_wc\file2.txt"
                 /logmsg:"test log message" /closeonend:0

TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\svn_wc\" /closeonend:0

TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt"
                 /startrev:50 /endrev:60 /closeonend:0

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html